# Python parsing string -> binary tree

Tags: python, string, data-structures, binary-tree, string-formatting

I want to create a binary tree by parsing a string like "27(3(4,5),2(,))". Where 27 is the root key and 3 is its left child and 2 is its right child.... I want to split at the commas and then recursively call the function again on the subtrees. First I want to disregard negative numbers. If a left or right subtree is not existing it will be None. I think I am close but I somehow cant figure out what I am doing wrong. Maybe replacing the commas with parenthesis could make it easier. At the moment the right subtree seems to be problematic.
Thanks for any approach or hint in advance!

This is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def createTree(string):
    if string is None or string == "":
        return None

    # Parse the key (can be more than one digit)
    key = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(string) and string[i] != "(":
        key = key * 10 + int(string[i])
        i += 1

    # Creating node
    node = Node(key)

    # Check if leaf node
    if i == len(string):
        return node

    # Finding the index of the comma that separates the left and right subtree
    leftStart = i
    leftParenthesesCount = 0
    for j in range(i, len(string)):
        if string[j] == "(":
            leftParenthesesCount += 1
        elif string[j] == ")":
            leftParenthesesCount -= 1
        elif string[j] == "," and leftParenthesesCount == 1:
            break

    #   index of closing parenthesis for the left subtree
    leftEnd = j
    leftParenthesesCount = 1
    for j in range(j + 1, len(string)):
        if string[j] == "(":
            leftParenthesesCount += 1
        elif string[j] == ")":
            leftParenthesesCount -= 1
            if leftParenthesesCount == 0:
                break

    # index of the closing parenthesis for right subtree
    rightEnd = len(string) - 1
    rightParenthesesCount = 1
    for j in range(len(string) - 2, -1, -1):
        if string[j] == ")":
            rightParenthesesCount += 1
        elif string[j] == "(":
            rightParenthesesCount -= 1
            if rightParenthesesCount == 0:
                break

    # Recursively constructing the left and right subtrees
    if leftStart + 1 < leftEnd:
        node.left = createTree(string[leftStart + 1:leftEnd])
    if leftEnd + 2 < rightEnd:
        node.right = createTree(string[leftEnd + 2:rightEnd])

    return node
```

I also wrote some testcases:

```
str = "35(22(7,2),5(4,))"
str2 = "27(2,)" 
str3 = "6(5,4)" 
str4 = "3(2,)" 
str5 = "1(,52)" 
str6 = "567(,35(16(89(,22(55(55(92,12),12(1(,12(14,15(16,17(,92(,92))))),92(92,))),16(,1(1(,13(,77)),)))),),35(35,)))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, just change the last part where you built the right subtree

```
# Recursively constructing the left and right subtrees
""" Search for the right subtree by checking if there is a non-empty   
substring between the end of the left subtree AND the end of str.   
# strip() allows to  remove any leading or trailing whitespace,  
to avoid to use the comma as the separator between left and right   
subtrees when it's the rightmost subtree and write the input str   
as str = "35(22(7,2),5(4))" rather than str = "35(22(7,2),5(4,))"
"""
    ...
    if leftStart + 1 < leftEnd:
        node.left = createTree(string[leftStart + 1:leftEnd])
    if j + 1 < rightEnd and string[leftEnd + 1:].strip():
        node.right = createTree(string[leftEnd + 1:])
```

I've used this method (external to the class) to print the tree on terminal and check:

```
def print_visited_tree(node, depth=0):
    if node is None:
        return

    print(f"{' ' * depth}{node.key}")
    print_visited_tree(node.left, depth + 1)
    print_visited_tree(node.right, depth + 1)

str = "27(3(4,5),2(,))"

tree1 = createTree(str)
print_visited_tree(tree1)
```

The output is :

```
27
 3
  4
  5
 2
  0
```

Hope it was want you wanted! Bye!

Answer (score 0):

When you use recursion (good), there should not be any need to count parentheses, since each level of recursion will be a responsible for an opening and closing one.

Also, I would first identify the tokens in the input string (use `re`), so you no longer have to fiddle with individual digits, but get the numbers in one go.

```
import re

def createTree(string):
    tokens = iter(re.findall(r"\d+|.", string))

    def dfs(terminal):
        node = None
        token = next(tokens, "")
        if token.isdigit():
            node = Node(int(token))
            token = next(tokens, "")
            if token == "(":
                node.left = dfs(",")
                node.right = dfs(")")
                token = next(tokens, "")
        if token != terminal:
            raise ValueError(f"not expected '{token}'")
        return node
        
    return dfs("")
```